# Can an iOS app "reregister" to handle a URL scheme without reinstallation?

Tags: ios

An iOS app can register to handle a URL scheme when it's installed.

Officially, "if more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme," according to [the "Communicating with Other Apps" section of Apple's "Advanced App Tricks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).

In practice, though, it seems like the app that most recently registered to handle that URL scheme is the one that it's given to. In the event that a second app has registered to handle a URL scheme for which an app is already registered, is it possible for the first app to somehow "reregister" to handler the URL scheme without reinstallation?

Comment: No. Once two apps register the same custom URL scheme, the only option is to delete one app and reboot the iOS device so the one left regains control of the custom scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no proof for this at hand, but I am pretty sure that registration for URL schemes as well as registration for file type handling etc. is an installation time procedure.

However, from my experience, providing an update via the app store and updating the app triggers this installation procedure (since the updated app may register new URL schemes). Hence, if you keep your apps "up to date" by providing frequent updates, iOS should prefer it (and from this point of view, the unofficial rule that the most recent handler is used, makes sense).